# Selectbox OnChange copy this text to div

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

How can I change the div text to Selectbox option selected text...

I have a selectbox with more than 100 values

---

**Scenario:**
As soon as I select an option from selectbox, the same option value(text) has to be replaced by relevant div text which it has `ccy` class `<div class="ccy">blablabla</div>` class...

---

**Eg:** I have a selectbox with EUR, USD, JPY, INR etc... If I select **EUR** from selectbox, the relevant divs which has class **ccy** `<div class='ccy'>currency 1</div><div class='ccy'>currency 2</div>` should be changed to `<div class='ccy'>EUR</div><div class='ccy'>EUR</div>` and so on...

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ts0L5xej/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="currencty-selectbox">
    <option value="1">EUR</option>
    <option value="2">USD</option>
    <option value="3">JPY</option>
    <option value="4">CAD</option>
    <option value="5">MXN</option>
    <option value="6">CZK</option>
</select>


<div class='ccy'>currency 1</div>
<div class='ccy'>currency 2</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#currencty-selectbox').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":selected").text() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#currencty-selectbox').on('change', function () {
    $('.ccy').text($(this).find(":selected").text());
    // ^^^^^^
}).trigger('change');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ts0L5xej/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this if you have same orders

This will work for all other currencies also

```
$('#currencty-selectbox').on('change', function() {
selected = $(this).find(":selected");
$("div[class^=c]").eq(selected.index()).text(selected.text());
}).trigger("change");
```

**DEMO:**

```js
$('#currencty-selectbox').on('change', function() {
  selected = $(this).find(":selected");
   $("div[class^=c]").eq(selected.index()).text(selected.text());
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="currencty-selectbox">
    <option value="1">EUR</option>
    <option value="2">USD</option>
    <option value="3">JPY</option>
    <option value="4">CAD</option>
    <option value="5">MXN</option>
    <option value="6">CZK</option>
</select>


<div class='ccy'>currency 1</div>
<div class='ccy'>currency 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ts0L5xej/
You can do it by adding following inside of your `change` event handler.

```
   $('.ccy').text($(this).find(":selected").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `trigger` the `change` event and place the text.

```
$('#currencty-selectbox').on('change', function() {
  $('.ccy').text( $(this).find(":selected").text() );
});
$('#currencty-selectbox').trigger('change');
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ts0L5xej/5/)

Answer (score 1):

To change the values inside te div use the same text() method you used, but with a value like `$('.ccy').text('some new text')`

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ts0L5xej/4/) updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".ccy").text($(this).find(":selected").text());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ts0L5xej/2/)